# Joomla Plugin With Helper File

Tags: joomla-3.x, development, plugin

Is there a conventional way of making a helper file to a Joomla Plugin? Like class names (helper or plgNameHelper) and the way of calling it?

```
class Helper
{
    public static function test() 
    {
    // some code
    }

    public static function anotherTest() 
    {
    // some code
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this probably a very noob question, but what is a (Joomla) "helper file" in this context? At first I thought it was some way to document your plugin for other developers, but judging by the answer I guess not!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Here is a small example:

**myplugin.php**

```
class Myplugin
{
    public function doSomething()
    {
        require_once __DIR__ . '/helper.php';
        $newuser = new User;

        return $newuser->getUsername();
    }
}
```

**helper.php**

```
class User
{
    public function getUsername()
    {
        // perform some magic
    }
}
```

Put both the PHP files in the same directory and simply call it using:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/helper.php';
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It helped a lot. The class name in helper file should respect any kind of Joomla terminology?

Comment: Of course, I would refrain from using Joomla class names. It would be best to use your plugin name as a prefix, for example: `MypluginUser`

Comment: @Lodder could you use `JLoader::import` instead of require once?  Are there any differences/benefits?

Comment: @Eoin if you like, yes

Comment: Is there a "right way"?  Forgive the inane questions, still learning

Comment: @Eoin - `\JLoader::register('MyCustomClass', __DIR__ . '/helper.php');`

Comment: I mean is it better/worse/same than require_once?

Comment: Please check the docs for JLoader. It will explain what it does